# Using a wysiwyg text editor to create emails

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce, phpmailer

I have created an admin part of my website and part of this is going to be used for sending out newsletters to people who have subscribed to them. The person who is going to be doing this has no coding experience which is why the emails can't be created just by using php/html.

What I've tried to do is use a wysiwyg text editor to make this easier for them. I have used tinymce for this. However I get issues when it comes to adding images, they won't show in outlook or gmail at all if the image has been uploaded. This isn't great as it means the only way to upload images is by just copying an image address from a website and adding them that way. Another issue is that although on the editor you can resize the image, once the email has been sent the original image size is what is sent. I have tried to get this working by doing the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
      convert_urls: false,
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
    theme: "modern",
    paste_data_images: false,
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
      "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar1: "sizeselect | fontselect |  fontsizeselect |insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | editimage | imageoptions",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
      if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
        $('#upload').trigger('click');
        $('#upload').on('change', function() {
          var file = this.files[0];
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            callback(e.target.result, {
              alt: ''
            });
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
      }
    },
    templates: [{
      title: 'Test template 1',
      content: 'Test 1'
    }, {
      title: 'Test template 2',
      content: 'Test 2'
    }]
  });
});
  </script> 



  <style>
  .hidden{display:none;}
  </style>




</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <?php include('menu.php');?>
    <p><a href="./">JG Ross Admin Index</a></p>

    <h2>Send Email</h2>
    <p>(Both subject and content must be filled out in order to send the email)</p>

    <?php

    //if form has been submitted process it
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );

        //collect form data
        extract($_POST);

        //very basic validation
        if($subject ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the title.';
        }


        if($emailCont ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the content.';
        }

        if(!isset($error)){



        }

    }

    //check for any errors
    if(isset($error)){
        foreach($error as $error){
            echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form action='createEmail.php' method='post'>

        <div id="toolbar-container"></div>

        <p><label>Subject</label><br />
        <input type='text' name='subject' required value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['subject'];}?>'></p>

        <p><label>Content</label><br />
        <textarea name='emailCont' id="emailCont" cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['emailCont'];}?></textarea></p>
         <input name="image" type="file" id="upload" class="hidden" onchange="">

        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>

    </form>

</div>


    </body>


    </html>
```

The page for sending the email is as follows:

```
<?php
// Starting session
require_once('../includes/config.php');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'C:\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-master\src\Exception.php';
require 'C:\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-master\src\PHPMailer.php';
require 'C:\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-master\src\SMTP.php';



$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$body = $_POST['emailCont'];



$sql = "SELECT email FROM subscribers";

    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {


$message  = "<html><body>";



$message .= "<table width='100%' bgcolor='#e0e0e0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";

$message .= "<tr><td>";

$message .= "<table align='center' width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='max-width:650px; background-color:#fff; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'>";

$message .= "<thead>
  <tr height='80'>
  <th colspan='4' style='background-color:#f5f5f5; border-bottom:solid 1px #bdbdbd; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size: 27px;' >Newsletter</th>
  </tr>
             </thead>";

$message .= "<tbody>

       <tr height='80'>
       <td colspan='4' align='center' style='background-color:#f5f5f5;'>
       <img scr = $body>

       </td>
       </tr>

        <tr height='20'>
       <td colspan='4' align='center' style='background-color:#f5f5f5;'>

        <p 'font-size:8px;'><a href='http://localhost/jgross/unsubscribe.php'>Unsubscribe</a></p>


       </td>
       </tr>


              </tbody>";

$message .= "</table>";

$message .= "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";

$message .= "</body></html>";



$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);


try {

   $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->SetFrom('donotreply@mydomain.com', $subject);
    $mail->AddAddress($row['email']);
   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
   $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Username = '********';
   $mail->Password = '********';
   $mail->Port = 587;

       if ($mail->addReplyTo('********')) {
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Body = $message;



               //Send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            //The reason for failing to send will be in $mail->ErrorInfo

            $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
        } else {
            $msg = 'The Newsletter was sucessfully sent<br>';
            header("Refresh:3; url=index.php");
            echo "The Newsletter was sucessfully sent<br>";

        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Invalid email address, message ignored.';
    }





}catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->errorMessage();
    $mail->smtp->reset();
}

 $mail->clearAddresses();



}
```

When I look at the image source after it has been updated, it is something like:

blob:http://localhost/d27a27cd-32a3-443e-ad7c-f3bf745fa500

Could that be an issue?

Is there a way to get this working so that the images go through and at the size I resize them to? Or am I wasting my time trying to do this? If so what would be a better way for sending newsletters out to subscribers?

Comment: You need to store uploaded and resized images somewhere that is web-accessible - then you will be able to reference the images from your email html. As you’re finding, there’s a lot involved in doing all this, so you may find it easier to use a service to take care of it for you, along with things like unsubscribe links, click tracking, privacy obligations and the rest. Take a look at the service I run, linked from my profile.

Comment: Might be something I need to discuss with the people I'm designing the website for. Is there any material that you know of that I can look at to help me learn how to do this sort of thing?

Comment: That's a very broad question - you need to be familiar with all the tech requirements of HTML, email content, email infrastructure, delivery throttling, image processing, privacy laws and lots more. There is a ton of documentation and content relating to all of these subjects independently, and you need to deal with all of them. Put it another way; your client probably doesn't have sufficient budget to cover you building this all yourself just for them. That's why external services exist.

Comment: Ah, never realised just how complex it would be. Thanks for explaining it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue and isn't aware like I was, there is an external plugin you can add to tinymce called Responsive filemanager which can be found here: https://www.responsivefilemanager.com/. Once added you are able to store images and can send images through email without any issues.

Note: images won't display on email if done through localhost, needs to be done through a proper website, eg. I'm using 000webhost.

Also it does not work on the latest version of tinymce(as far as I'm aware), tried it and it did not work. So, I'm using version 4.3.3 and it works without any issues.

Hope this can help someone